# VS 2015 and FLTK Callback issue

Tags: c++, callback, visual-studio-2015, fltk

I am trying to move my FLTK projects and compile it under the VS 2015 community edition. While do this, I am getting error. I have a code like below:

```
#include <Fl/....>
....
class CWindow
{
private:
    ....
    Fl_Input *_textInputEditor;
    ....
    void _cbTextInput(Fl_Widget *refObject, void *objData)
    {
        // Do something when callback is triggered.
    }
public:
....
    void createWindow()
    {
        ....
        _textInputEditor = new Fl_Input(....);
        _textInputEditor->when(FL_WHEN_ENTER_KEY);
        _textInputEditor->callback((Fl_Callback*)&CWindow::_cbTextInput, this);
        ....
```

When I try to compile, I get an error:

`Error  C2440   'type cast': cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall CWindow::* )(Fl_Widget *,void *)' to 'Fl_Callback (__cdecl *)`

This same code compiles with MinGW 5.x perfectly (IDE: C::B) under Win 7.

Can someone help me here? I want a call back to a private method of my CWindow class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature is incorrect.  _cbTextInput should be static.  The problem then will be access to member variables.

```
static void _cbTextInput(Fl_Widget *refObject, void *objData)
{
    // No access to member variables so cast it to a CWindow* to get
    // at the member variables
    CWindow* self = (CWindow*) objData;
    self->cbTextInput();

    // Alternatively, if you do not wish to write another routine,
    // you will need to put self-> in front of every member variable
    // you wish to access.  Just personal preference: some people prefer
    // it that way.
}

void cbTextInput()
{
    // This has access to member variables
    ...
}
```

Comment: I had tried this earlier, but I get this error: `Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___strdup`. Also why did this compile and work in MinGW?

Comment: It compiles because of the cast.  If you remove the cast, the build will probably fail.  If you build with -Wall, it will tell you about what you're doing illegally.  The strdup problem is a different one: the compilation model (MD, MT, MDD or MTD) of your compilation is different from that of your libraries.

Comment: thanks. This worked. But any idea why my old code (without static) compiled and build successfully in mingw 5.x?

Comment: Does it compile without the cast?

Comment: I've just tried it with mingw: comes up with the same errors without the static.  I am using version 4.8.1.